# Spring - read value from application.yml in @Entity class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class User {

    @Id
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @Transient
    private String config;

    @PostLoad
    private void setConfig(){
        //I would like to initialize config (transient) field after loading from database using configuration from application.yml
    }
```

In setConfig() I would like to read values from application.yml. What is the possibility to read this? @Value not working. I try also use static class but static class not read values from configuration file.

Comment: why you want to do this in `Entity`?

Comment: @Deadpool because I use Spring Data Rest and `@Transient` field. I would like to initialize this field for every objects after reading from database (using `@PostLoad`). I must use string from configuration application.yml file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@Value` will work only when used in a spring managed bean. Entities however are not managed by Spring.

One solution would be to read the value in some managed bean at boot time and then store to some static variable, then you can just read the value of this variable inside your `setConfig()` method.

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationStartupConfig implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public static String prop;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(final ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
        prop = env.getProperty("property.path");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @ahmed,

Your solution works, and I have upvoted it too. but I do have a question for you though. shouldn't be the ```private static String prop``` public instead of private?

Comment: yes you're right, to access it from the entity it must either be public or you create a public getter for it (edited to public in answer)